# What is the maximum length a MC68030 can be placed away from Commodore CDTV motherboard, without affecting timings?

Tags: noise, resistance, signal-processing, homebrew-cpu

I want to fit a [TF536](http://www.amibay.com/showthread.php?112360-TF536-030-64-MB-IDE-internal-expansion-for-the-A500&highlight=Tf536) accelerator card into the Commodore CDTV case, which is a challenge from the perspective of available space.

[image: MC68000 CPU]

[image: TF]

I know there is a [relocator](https://github.com/SukkoPera/Open68000Relocator/tree/master) board project available, but it still doesn't fit the case. The only way I could possibly make it work is by mounting the accelerator card underneath the motherboard. This would however require extension wires from the 68000 socket of around 3-4 inches (7.5-10cm). Is it even possible to create such an extension, and does it make sense? Will I mess up the timings or other parameters of the CPU due to delay (wire length vs traces)?

Comment: My *guess*: these old computers run at quite slow (for today) speeds and don't need very much attention paid to timing. 3-4 inches will be fine.

Comment: Would it have a low enough profile if you removed the 68000 socket and wired the TF536 directly to the motherboard?

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about adding 0.5 nanoseconds of delay. With the slow edges, that should be still fine.

You also are talking about adding 100+ nanoHenries of inductance; I use 25nanoHenry/inch as a rule of thumb.

To survive that, add 0.1uF across VDD/GND pairs that power the 68030. You must install these capacitors right at the DIP pins

Also, the clock lines could use 220 ohms in series, to dampen overshoots, in either direction.

===========================

The ground pin has to handle all the fast IN/OUT currents. So make the Ground extension be a wide piece of braid or a dozen stranded wires all in parallel.